# read xml with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to read the names form this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://mysite.com/">
   <name>2</name>
   <name>3</name>
   <name>4</name>
</string>
```

Tried:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(s);
foreach (var v in doc.Descendants("name"))
{
    //do work
}
```

but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a custom namespace - you need to specify the namespace when you select the elements - try this (tested and worked):

```
XNamespace  xmlns = "http://mysite.com/";
var doc = XElement.Parse(s);
foreach (var v in doc.Descendants(xmlns + "name"))
{
    //do work
}
```

Comment: Thats right. `XName.Get("{http://mysite.com/}name")` or `XName.Get("http://mysite.com/", "name")` should work, too (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741.aspx)